# OOP style coding

Tags: php

Update
As per the instruction of experts, I've modified the code this way:

```
<?php
//Class Validation
class transaction_validate{
    
private $val_id;
    function __construct($id) {
        $this->val_id = $id;
    }

public function status(){
    //Call our server and decode json value
    $data = $this->get_data($this->val_id);
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    return $obj->status;
}

public function amount(){
    //Call our server and decode json value
    $data = $this->get_data($this->val_id);
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    return $obj->amount;
}


//Create a function for fetching data
private function get_data($sid){
    $url = 'https://domain.com/verify/process.php?trx='.$sid;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
}

$validate = new transaction_validate();
$validate->val_id = '5201211120944';
echo $validate->amount();
echo '<br>';
echo $validate->status();
```

And output is

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for transaction_validate::__construct(),
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access private property transaction_validate::$val_id

Confused!

============================Previous Question======================================

I'm just learning OOP style PHP coding. Tried to code a script for personal usage which seems wrong. Code is:

```
<?php
//Class Validation
class transaction_validate{
    
    var $val_id;
    
    public function status(){
        //Call our server and decore json value
        $data = get_data();
        $obj = json_decode($data);
        
        return $obj->status;
    }
    
    public function amount(){
        //Call our server and decore json value
        $data = get_data();
        $obj = json_decode($data);
        
        return $obj->amount;
    }

    
    //Create a function for featching data
    private function get_data($val_id){
        $url = 'https://domain.com/verify/process.php?trx='.$val_id;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}

$validate = new transaction_validate('5201211120944');
echo $validate->amount();
echo '<br>';
echo $validate->status();
```

And output is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_data() in
> /home/userdo/public_html/class.php on line 17

I need to recognize what wrong I did.

Comment: Short story (there is more you can do here...): you should add a constructor ($val_id isn't being set as an object member anywhere in your class), and `get_data()` should be `$this->get_data()`

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply. But constructor for which part? Get Data via cURL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell PHP the function is in the class context:

```
$this->get_data()
```

As mentioned in comments, you should add a constructor to set the id you are passing in...

```
class transaction_validate{

    private $val_id;

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->val_id = $id;
    }

    //...
```

Also, if you are writing OOP, validation probably belongs on the domain entity that represents a transaction, rather than in a validation helper class.

Comment: @PHPLearner I think you've missed out the `__construct` function in my answer - this is what takes the id and puts it into the private variable. Once you've done that, you need to change `$val_id` to `$this->val_id` wherever you want to use the id.

Comment: I've updated the question again, I've tried with that but failed. Can you please check and help me in correcting?

Comment: `$validate = new transaction_validate(); $validate->val_id = '5201211120944';` is incorrect - you just use `$validate = new transaction_validate('5201211120944');`

Answer (score 1):

This is because `get_data()` is not defined in the global scope but in the `transaction_validate` class (by the way, I'd recommend to change it to `TransactionValidate`; this is one of the OOP naming conventions).

To call functions (in OOP – methods), you need to use the variable `$this`, which basically points to the current instance of a class (in this case – instance of `transaction_validate`.

So the code should look like this:

```
$data = $this->get_data();
```

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a function defined in the class it must be invoked using class instance i.e object of class in which function is defined.

In the above example get_data is a private function defined in class and according to principle of data hiding of OOP private members are accessible within the same class only
They are hidden outside the class means private members cannot be invoked outside the class definition.

So it will be invoked in following manner

```
<?php

   //Class Validation
  class transaction_validate{

var $val_id;

public function status(){
    //Call our server and decore json value
    $data =$this->get_data();
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    return $obj->status;
}

public function amount(){
    //Call our server and decore json value
    $data = $this0get_data();
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    return $obj->amount;
}


//Create a function for featching data
private function get_data($val_id){
    $url = 'https://domain.com/verify/process.php?trx='.$val_id;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
}

         $validate = new transaction_validate('5201211120944');
         echo $validate->amount();
          echo '<br>';
         echo $validate->status();
```

Comment: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for transaction_validate::get_data()` output is like this, and if I use `$data =$this->get_data($val_id);` output is completely empty.